# /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount does not exist on new google cloud instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run my first ever google VM following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server) which says to run the command

> sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/disk/by-id/google-minecraft-disk /home/minecraft

But, there is no /usr/share/google directory on my VM, so no safe_format_and_mount.

This is what I see in /usr/share:

[image]

How do I format the volume I created? or, where is this safe_format_and_mount executable?

Answer (score 3):

To format the drive I used

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/disk/by-id/google
-minecraft-disk
```

Comment: That's the correct command for formatting the disk. 'safe_format_and_mount' has been deprecated. We'll update the document soon.

Comment: The documentation has been updated on 21st of Nov 2016.

Comment: When was this deprecation of `safe_format_and_mount` introduced, @Kamran? Has there been a changelog/blog article/any notification about that?

Comment: @Greg Dubicki, it was notified through [deprecation warnings](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/commit/82b75f314528b90485d5239ab5d5495cc22d775f) in the latest release of [safe_format_and_mount script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/legacy/google-startup-scripts/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount).

Answer (score 0):

```
log warn "====================================================================="
log warn "WARNING: safe_format_and_mount is deprecated."
log warn "See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks"
log warn "for additional instructions."
log warn "====================================================================="
```

source : https://gist.github.com/dcgoss/254262db0dfd151ecf51

Comment: Can you add some more details please